# Menubar that stays fixed after scrolling doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below I have pasted my html, css and my js.
Im trying to get my menubar to stay fixed to the top once the user has scrollen down to 500px. The menubar doesn't attain the fixed attribute once scrolled down to 500px.

What am I doing wrong here?
I got the idea from this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/criddlecraddle/wj9dd/)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="menubar.css">
    <script src="menubar.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
    </header>

    <div class="container">

        <div id="Blackbar" class="clearfix">
            <nav id='nav_bar'>
                <ul class='nav_links'>
                    <li id="Home">
                        <a href="default.asp">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="Tracks">
                        <a href="default.asp">Tracks</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="Events">
                        <a href="default.asp">Events</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="Blog">
                        <a href="default.asp">Blog</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="About">
                        <a href="default.asp">About</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <div id="Content" class="clearfix">
            <div id="ArtikelFrame" class="clearfix">
                <p id="Koptekst">
                    Nieuwe muziek
                </p>
                <p id="Ondetitel">
                    Vrijdag 27 maart &#x7c; Budakid
                </p>
                <img id="ArtikelPlaatje" src="img/general-midi-logo.jpg" class="image" />
                <p id="TekstDeel1">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.&nbsp;
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </p>
                <p id="TekstDeel2">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula,
                    <br />
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="ArtikelFrame" class="clearfix">
                <p id="Koptekst">
                    Nieuwe muziek
                </p>
                <p id="Ondetitel">
                    Vrijdag 27 maart &#x7c; Budakid
                </p>
                <img id="ArtikelPlaatje" src="img/general-midi-logo.jpg" class="image" />
                <p id="TekstDeel1">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.&nbsp;
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </p>
                <p id="TekstDeel2">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula,
                    <br />
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="ArtikelFrame2" class="clearfix">
                <p id="Koptekst">
                    Nieuwe muziek
                </p>
                <p id="Ondetitel">
                    Vrijdag 27 maart &#x7c; Budakid
                </p>
                <img id="ArtikelPlaatje" src="img/general-midi-logo.jpg" class="image" />
                <p id="TekstDeel1">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.&nbsp;
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </p>
                <p id="TekstDeel2">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula,
                    <br />
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div id="Footer" class="clearfix">
        </div>


</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: 'AvenirNext';
    src: url('fonts/riesling.eot');
    src: local('AvenirNextLTProCn'), local('AvenirNextLTProCn'), url('fonts/AvenirNextLTProCn.otf') format('opentype');
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}

.container {
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 1025px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
}

nav {
    height: 60px;
    display: block;
    width: 1025px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #6e6e6e;
    z-index: 3;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.65em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
    margin-top: 14px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

header {
    background-image: url(img/10634107_736318616436352_1616233075386796082_o-2.jpg);
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

#Blackbar {
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

#Content {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    clear: both;
    width: 66.66%;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-right-color: rgb(156, 156, 156);
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-left-color: rgb(156, 156, 156);
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-left-style: solid;
}

#ArtikelFrame {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    clear: none;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: rgb(156, 156, 156);
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}

#ArtikelFrame2 {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    clear: none;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

#Koptekst {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-top: 4%;
    clear: none;
    min-height: 0px;
    margin-right: 4%;
}

#Ondetitel {
    float: left;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    clear: both;
    min-height: 0px;
    margin-right: 0%;
    color: rgb(156, 156, 156);
}

#ArtikelPlaatje {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-top: 4%;
    clear: both;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

#TekstDeel2 {
    float: left;
    font-size: 1em;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    clear: both;
    min-height: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
    margin-right: 4%;
}

#TekstDeel1 {
    float: left;
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 42%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    clear: none;
    min-height: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
    margin-right: 4%;
}

#Footer {
    float: left;
    height: 400px;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.navbar-fixed {
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#nav_bar {
    border: 0;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    height: 30px;
}

.nav_links {
    margin: 0;
}

.nav_links li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.nav_links li a {
    padding: 0 15.5px;
    color: #3498db;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                //if you hard code, then use console
                //.log to determine when you want the 
                //nav bar to stick.  
                console.log($(window).scrollTop())
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > 500) {
                    $('#nav_bar').addClass('navbar-fixed');
                }
                if ($(window).scrollTop() < 501) {
                    $('#nav_bar').removeClass('navbar-fixed');
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: So I've pasted your code into jsfiddle and everything seems to work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/Wj9dD/752/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included the jQuery library? I don't see that anywhere in your code. You can download the latest version of jQuery here: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js . Or if you want to browse around other jQuery versions, take a look here: https://code.jquery.com/

After that, save the jQuery library you want to the folder where your HTML page is located, and include it in a script tag. In the body of your HTML page, just above the  tag add

```
<script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Don't use external content.
But i have pasted your code in a fiddle and it works like a charm, looks like you have to include jQuery to the bottom (before <body> ends)

Comment: Edited it so it doesn't use external content.